# R list to serialize json

Tags: json, r

How ia can get json string using R-list?
im have ntext code

```
library(jsonlite)
x<-list(
  "a" = "test",
  "b" = 1,
  "c" = 2

)
serial_data<-toJSON( x )
```

but its return

```
{"a":["test"],"b":[1],"c":[2]}
```

im need next string

```
{"a":"test","b":1,"c":2}
```

Comment: `toJSON(x,auto_unbox=TRUE)` ? (from `?toJSON` "auto_unbox 
automatically unbox all atomic vectors of length 1.")

Comment: `?toJSON` will give you the options for that function.